# How to get Google Billing details programmatically?

Tags: api, google-api, billing

I'm using several **Google APIs** for my services and one of the boring tasks I need to execute everyday is to enter in **Google Developers Console** and check my current month balance. 
I'm wondering if there's an **API** in **Google** to check the **current month costs** without having to enter in **IAM** everytime. I've checked that Google Billing API doesn't have such a functionality but a lot of (unuseful) services like returning the name of the invoicing account or the name of the project.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to get this information is via a BigQuery export. You can configure it so that detailed billing data is automatically exported for you to query. Here are [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) on how to set up BigQuery export.

Another option is to have the billing data exported to a CSV or JSON file that is periodically placed in a GCS bucket. However, this type of export does not provide you with as detailed of information as the BigQuery export does. Here are [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file) on how to set up GCS export.